# Is there any way to get a list of locales that are defined in resConfig gradle?

Tags: android, localization

Basically I have defined locales in gradle like `resConfig("en", "ar")` is there any programmatic way to get the list of these locales?

**Update #1**

Right now I've defined an array in Gradle!

```
buildConfigField("String[]", "LOCALE", 'new String[]{"en", "ur", "ar"}')
```

And in my code get the list below!

```
fun getLocaleList(): Array<String> = BuildConfig.LOCALE
```

But I'm not sure there should be any other way to get the locales!